# why chrome console not show "\n" as string but console.log output as normal line break?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Version: 90.0.4430.212

type "1\n2" then type "enter" showing "\n" string

type "console.log('1\n2')" then type "enter" showing normal

[image]

Comment: When you press Enter, console shows the last expression which is the original string. When you run console.log, this function reads the `\n` control code and makes a new line accordingly because this is what control codes are for.

Answer (score 3):

The console reads the \n as new lines and outputs it the way it would look with the line breaks.

If you want to see the \n in console use JSON.stringify().

Example:

```js
 

console.log('1\n2');
console.log(JSON.stringify('1\n2'));
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not working anymore.